# Strange behaviour with jQuery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've suddenly gotten a very strange "bug". Up to now, this script has worked like a charm. But all of the sudden the `formData` variable is not passed through `jQuery.ajax`, as if it does not exist.

The funny thing is that if I trigger an `alert` displaying the data, it all works. But as soon as I remove the alert, the php script tells me that `formData` index is missing.

I'm clueless to what causes this or how to solve it :-/

This works fine on my development server, but not on the production server.

```
jQuery('#btn_saveForm').live('click', function() {
    var instance = 'update';
    var brand_id = jQuery('#itemID').val();

    // Get form data
    var form_data = jQuery("#data_form").serialize();

    // alert(form_data); //If I uncomment this, the script works...

    //Process form data
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/my_theme/include/jquery.php",
        data: {
            instance : instance, 
            formData : form_data, 
            brandID : brand_id
        },
        success: (function(feedback) {
            showFeedback(feedback);
        }),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a bit of a wild guess, but the fact it works on dev but not when deployed suggests to me an issue with establing the MIME type on the server, are you actually returning valid JSON? Might be one for fiddler or the NET tab in Firebug. Try adding an error: function(e) {} block as well and see what is contained within e on the server (again, via firebug - presuming VS is not available)

Comment: @SpaceBison - Thanks. Checking the NET tab in FF shows me that all the data IS actually being sent! But doing a `print_r($_REQUEST)` in the PHP code that is being called shows only `instance` and `brandID`.

Comment: @SpaceBison, it's not returning anything because the PHP file cannot find `$_REQUEST['formData']`.

Comment: @Steven could you post in your question the content of the `formData` variable as Firebug sees it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I just found the bug. I only get this error when the text in the description field is longer than 20 characters....

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's `serialize` that does not get enough time to fetch everything. This is frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that putting the `alert()` in allows the `form_data` and `brand_id`  variables to be filled completely before the AJAX request is sent. With that in mind, try this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/my_theme/include/jquery.php",
    data: {
        instance : instance, 
        formData : jQuery("#data_form").serialize(),
        brandID : jQuery('#itemID').val()
    },
    success: (function(feedback) {
        showFeedback(feedback);
    }),
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Alternatively, just to test, you could set `async: false` on the AJAX call to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, I've tried both your solutions, no luck. The script works fine on my local computer and on my dev server, but not on my prod server. I was working before I did som code changes, but I did not change this piece of code.

Comment: PS. see my comment to @SpaceBison

Comment: I discovered that if I use `serializearray` I do not get this error. If you have any more good tips, let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

try to restart browser / change browser to another and see whats happening then

Comment: It's the same on two different browsers

Answer (score 0):

If it's true that you have some races here (which would be very strange, as js is single-threaded), the following should help you:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: siteURL +"/wp-content/themes/my_theme/include/jquery.php",
        data: {
            instance : instance, 
            formData : form_data, 
            brandID : brand_id
        },
        success: (function(feedback) {
            showFeedback(feedback);
        }),
        dataType: 'json'
    })
}, 0);
```

The 0-timeout construction will put your code at the end of execution queue.

Comment: that did not have anny effect. Even set it to 1000.